# FTP not working UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

hi i have a script where i am performing sudo and going to particular directory,and within that directory editing files name as required. After getting required file name i want to FTP files on windows machine but script after reading FTP commands says-:

> -bash: line 19: quote: command not found
>
> -bash: line 20: quote: command not found
>
> -bash: line 21: put: command not found
>
> -bash: line 22: quit: command not found

My ftp is working if i run normally so it is some other problem.Script is below-:

```
#!/usr/bin/
path=/global/u70/glob
echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - glob  << 'EOF'
#ls -lrt
cd "$path"
pwd
for entry in $(ls -r)
  do
  if [ "$entry" = "ADM" ];then
   cd "$entry"

FileName=$(ls -t | head -n1)
echo "$FileName"

FileNameIniKey=$(ls -t | head -n1 | cut -c 12-20)
echo "$FileNameIniKey"

echo "$xmlFileName" >> "$xmlFileNameIniKey.ini"
chmod 755 "$FileName"
chmod 755 "$FileNameIniKey.ini"
ftp -n hostname
quote USER ftp
quote PASS
put "$FileName"
quit
rm "$FileNameIniKey.ini"
fi
done
EOF
```

Comment: You should pay great importance to what 'that other guy' said. Format your question better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your questions and make them easier to answer and more useful for future readers by including a minimal, self-contained example. Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -n mirrors.rit.edu
quote user anonymous
quote pass mypass
ls
```

When executed, you get a manual FTP session instead of a file listing:

```
$ ./myscript
Trying 2620:8d:8000:15:225:90ff:fefd:344c...
Connected to smoke.rc.rit.edu.
220 Welcome to mirrors.rit.edu.
ftp>
```

The problem is that you're assuming that a script is a series of strings that are automatically typed into a terminal. This is not true. It's a series of commands that are executed one after another.

Nothing happens with `quote user anonymous` until *AFTER* `ftp` has exited, and then it's run as a shell command instead of being written to the `ftp` command.

Instead, specify login credentials on the command line and then include commands in a here document:

```
ftp -n "ftp://anonymous:passwd@mirrors.rit.edu" << end
ls
end
```

This works as expected:

```
$ ./myscript
Trying 2620:8d:8000:15:225:90ff:fefd:344c...
Connected to smoke.rc.rit.edu.
220 Welcome to mirrors.rit.edu.
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||19986|).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxrwxr-x   12 3002     1000         4096 Jul 11 20:00 CPAN
drwxrwsr-x   10 0        1001         4096 Jul 11 21:08 CRAN
drwxr-xr-x   18 1003     1000         4096 Jul 11 18:02 CTAN
drwxrwxr-x    5 89987    546          4096 Jul 10 10:00 FreeBSD
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ftp -n "ftp://anonymous:passwd@mirrors.rit.edu" << end
```

Name or service not known

Comment: Please explain your answer.